# Jquery click function does not activate toggleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, click, toggleclass

**AIM:**  I plan on having multiple buttons.  Each button will appear one after the other and on clicking the button it will activate a css class with an animation inside it

**PROBLEM:** Initially, on clicking the first button this works. However the second button requires a double click before toggling the css class.

http://jsfiddle.net/grfLdyqw/

```
   $("#bt,#bt2").click(function () {
        $(".box1").toggleClass("box1-change");

        $("#bt").hide();
        $("#bt2").show();
   });
```

On the back of some research, I found that a solution to this was to create a separate click function in jquery for each button.

**NEW PROBLEM:** This now allows the 2nd button to be activated on one click but now the toggleClass does not fire.

http://jsfiddle.net/afj98q8n/

```
    $("#bt").click(function () {
        $(".box1").toggleClass("box1-change");

        $("#bt").hide();
        $("#bt2").show();
    });

    $("#bt2").click(function () {
        $(".box1").toggleClass("box1-change");

        $("#bt2").hide();
        $("#bt3").show();
    });
```

As a novice, I am now uncertain as to what to try next.  Hopefully someone can advise me on a solution to this issue?

Further down the line, I plan to activate/toggle an animation on the 'buttons' using a similar method before they disappear which might complicate this further?

Thanks.

**SOLVED:** http://jsfiddle.net/grfLdyqw/7/

Comment: 2 problems = 2 questions. : d

Comment: each even click removes your class. But animation related to class adding.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you for highlighting the even clicks. http://jsfiddle.net/afj98q8n/3/ getting closer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you click the first button the animation class is added to your div, the first click on the second button will remove the class from the div(toggle adds a class if it's not present and removes it if it's present), so that's why you always need to click it twice

This code will automatically remove the class after the 1.5 seconds need for the animation to finish

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bt").show();
    $("#bt2").hide();

    $("#bt,#bt2").click(function () {
        $(".box1").toggleClass("box1-change");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".box1").toggleClass("box1-change");
        }, 1500);

        $("#bt").hide();
        $("#bt2").show();
    });
});
```

The working jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/grfLdyqw/4/

Comment: It is better to add a class to the buttons and then just toggle the buttons class. in case more buttons need to be added: http://jsfiddle.net/grfLdyqw/6/

Comment: Having tried a few things - I now have a working example http://jsfiddle.net/grfLdyqw/7/



I cannot seem to get the suggested addClass/ removeClass method to work though :(

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think i found a way for you to get the desired effect by cloning the box, here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/grfLdyqw/9/ hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

in the second click function instead of toggle us addClass.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#bt").show();
    $("#bt2").hide();
    $("#bt3").hide();

    $("#bt").click(function () {
        $(".box1").toggleClass("box1-change");

        $("#bt").hide();
        $("#bt2").show();
    });

    $("#bt2").click(function () {
        $(".box1").addClass("box1-change");

        $("#bt2").hide();
        $("#bt3").show();
    });
});
```